# What is the probability that at the end of the sequence, bucket B contains ball bi

Tags: probability

We have a bucket *B* which can store 1 ball at a time. Imagine a sequence of balls: {*b<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>2</sub>....b<sub>n</sub>*} such that ball *b<sub>i</sub>* appears after ball *b<sub>i-1</sub>* in the sequence. The *i<sup>th</sup> b<sub>i</sub>* is stored in bucket B with probability `1/i` replacing the ball *b<sub>k</sub>*,previously stored. For each i, what is the probability that at the end of the sequence, bucket B contains ball *b<sub>i</sub>*.

Comment: k is less than i (k <i).

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Does $b_1$ start in $B$?  If there are, say, two balls, is the answer just $\frac 12$ for both (as there is a $\frac 12$ probability that $b_2$ replaces $b_1$)?

Comment: To be clear: $B$ always contains exactly one ball (since $b_1$ was put in there with probability $1$) and whether a given ball is put in $B$ is independent of the previous balls? In which case, it seems that at the end of the day the probability that $b_i$ is in $B$ is simply the probability that it was put there $1/i$), times that none after was put instead ($\prod_{j>i}(1-1/j)$) by independence.

Comment: But why do you refer to the $(i-1)^{st}$ $b_i$?  There's only one $b_i$, right?

Comment: My reading is the same as that of @ClementC.  but I am not sure we have the question right.

Comment: @lulu I would bet on "typo/confusing notation." This should most likely read $(i-1)$st ball, a.k.a. $b_{i-1}$.

Comment: By the way, if the above indeed captures the question, then the answer is, perhaps counter-intuitively,  [$$\frac{1}{i}\prod_{j=i+1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{j}\right) = \frac{1}{n}.$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fi+*+Product%5B1-1%2Fj,+%7Bj,i%2B1,n%7D%5D)

Comment: @lulu,  its i-th ball. Sorry guys about the confusion.

Comment: @ClementC.:  You have it right.  If you combine your two comments you have a nice answer.

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you for the solution. Why does probability problems seem so difficult before and seem so trivial after knowing the solution.

Comment: @RossMillikan Added... not detailed further, though. (@papabiceps: pretty much the story of my academic life so far.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B$ always contains exactly one ball (since $b_1$ was put in there with probability $1$) and whether a given ball $b_i$ is put in the bucket $B$ is independent of the previous balls ($i < j$). Therefore, at the end of the day the probability that $b_i$ is in the bucket $B$ is simply the probability
$$
\mathbb{P}\{b_i\in B\text{ and } b_j\not\in B \text{ for all } j > i\}
$$
which, by independence, becomes
$$
\mathbb{P}\{b_i\in B \}\cdot\prod_{j=i+1}^n \mathbb{P}\{b_j\not\in B\} = \frac{1}{i}\prod_{j=i+1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{j}\right).
$$

This in turn, perhaps counter-intuitively,  leads to the answer being
[$$\frac{1}{i}\prod_{j=i+1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{j}\right) = \frac{1}{n}.$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fi+*+Product%5B1-1%2Fj,+%7Bj,i%2B1,n%7D%5D)

*(This last identity is easy to show, e.g. by induction on $1\leq i \leq n$.)*

Comment: (since b1b1 was put in there with probability 11). There's a typo *probability 1* not 11

Comment: @papabiceps Thanks for spotting this! Apparently, copy-pasting from comments involves the joy of all $\LaTeX$ being duplicated in the plain text.